# Forecasting Model on Cross sectional data

Tags: time-series

I have a dataset of weekly shortage data and categorical features such as origin and product type and numerical side I have demand qty. this weekly shortage data is for each product type and for the specific origin. I don't know how to proceed it as a time series model or regression model kindly help

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you do not have any information about the specific dates; so this won't be a time series problem; it would be a regression model.

If you would have the dates information for each week in the dataset then it would have been a time series problem.

Comment: I just have week number and year eg fy202323

Comment: Could you share a sample row along with the column names of your dataset?